# Display Button as long as ListView doesn't has more than five Items

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem, datatrigger

I have some `ListViews` who each can contain max 5 `ListViewItems`. As long as there are less than 5 items there should be an `Button` be displayed. I have already written an `Value Converter` that returns true if the Count is less than five. But now I have Problems styling my `ListView`. Because i.e. if there are three `ListViewItems` they should be styled with the normal style and the "4" item should be an `Button`. My tought was that I add a new `ListViewItem` inside the `DataTrigger`. Is that possible or is there a better way to achive that?

**Style.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="5" Columns="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>      
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource ItemCounterConverter}}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>No items to display</TextBlock>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!--ListViewItem-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">                                    
                <Border BorderBrush="#5076A7" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#C0D3EA" Offset="1.0"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <StackPanel TextElement.FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextElement.FontSize="12">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Betreff}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Button FontSize="7" Content="X" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Kunde}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Ort}"/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="3,0,0,0" Text="("/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alternative}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=")"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update**
Thanks this looks very promising and you understood it right. But I have problems implementing it. Every `ListView` has a differnt `ItemSource`(they're all `ObservableCollections`), so I don't know if I can set the `ItemSource` inside the `Style`?  But the Button at the End should be available to all of them. My `Styles` are in a different File than the `ListViews` themselves. The definition for my `ListViews` looks like this:

**AppointmentOverview.xaml**

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Mov}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Mon}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Div}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Div}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Miv}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Min}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Dov}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Don}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Frv}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Frn}"/>
```

Comment: Why not just put the button below the ListView

Comment: There is no place under the `ListView`.